# Jquery next prev with text

Tags: jquery

Hello everyone I'm trying to do that I have two buttons which are call "next" and "prev" which  provides hide and show text. My first text must be display like "1" when I click prev button it will come 2 and press again until fourt text whiich I call "4" Here is html part :

```
<button id="slider1next" >Next</button>
<br>
  <p class="text" id="first_one">1</p>
    <p class="text" id="second_one" style="display:none">2</p>
    <p class="text" id="third_one" style="display:none">3</p>
<p class="text" id="fourth_one" style="display:none">4</p>
<br>
<button id="slider2next" >Prev</button>​
```

I want to press next button again and I want to display first text which is call "1" and also I click prev button it must show previous text

Here is my script

```
$("#slider1next").click(function() {
    var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();
});

$("#slider2next").click(function() {
    var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().prev();
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:last").show();
});​
```

And also you can see http://jsfiddle.net/ganymedes/scXQR/

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you want to go back to 1 after 4?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ganymedes/scXQR/ please click next button until 4 then press again nothing will be display I want to  press again the next button and show 1 and press prev button show 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using selector in Next Method:

```
$("#slider1next").click(function() {
    var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next('p');
    $next.length ? $next.show() : $(".text:first").show();
});
```

Here is edit to your code http://jsfiddle.net/scXQR/5/

Hope this helps.